fbox with multiple lines in lower right corner of page?
I want to put a framed box with text in the lower right corner of the page. The whole page is in a picture environment. The content is programmatically created (from a database), so the amount of text will vary - in some cases it will short (e.g. "3 copies"), and in other cases it will also have a list of names. I like the fact that fbox will size itself to fit the contents, but I have two things I can't figure out how to do.
(1) When there are multiple lines (the list of names), I don't know how to have line breaks without using something like parbox or minipage, both of which need a width defined. That defeats the flexibility of fbox. I tried \fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{Test}}, but the box goes all the way to (or beyond) the right edge of the page, so I guess the \linewidth is not the width of the actual line of text.
(2) The X and Y values for \put(X,Y) seem to mean the left edge of the box and the vertical middle. If there is a way to make it mean the bottom right instead, I can't figure it out. The code I'm writing that gets the data from the database and generates the .tex file will know the number of lines, so it could calculate an appropriate Y value, but X is more problematic, as it's not a fixed-space font.
Here is a minimum example that includes all the packages and setup of the real thing (because I don't know how much of it matters for this) but only one page and only the fbox part, not the other items on the page:
\documentclass{ujarticle}
\usepackage{plext}
\usepackage[uplatex]{otf}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\graphicspath {{/var/www/kizunadb/public/graphics/}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\noindent
\raggedright
\sffamily
\gtfamily
\begin{picture}(210,297)(3,3)

\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}
\put(105,50){\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
  5 copies\\
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
  Doe, John (1)\\
  Jones, Samuel & Sally (1)\\
  Smith, George (3)
  }}}

\end{picture}
\clearpage
\end{document}

Update: After tweaking John Kormylo's answer to fit some coding constraints, I might be close. The only remaining problem is that when the savebox is defined inside the picture environment, the line spacing of the text inside the box becomes extra tall (2.57 according to Acrobat Pro) for some mysterious reason. If I can tame that, I'll be satisfied. This is my current iteration (the part between the blank lines in the MWE above - everything else is unchanged):
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}
\savebox\tempbox{\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% use only as much space as needed
\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont 5 copies\\
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont Doe, John (1)\\
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont Jones, Samuel \& Sally (1)\\
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont Smith, George (3)
\end{tabular}}}% measure size
\put({\dimexpr 200mm-\wd\tempbox},{\dimexpr 10mm+\dp\tempbox}){\usebox\tempbox}

Update #2: I decided there might be other benefits to the triple-function-call approach (see comments under John's answer for what I mean by that), so I implemented it and then went back into the revision history on John's answer to get older versions of his code before he tried to work around that limitation. I would prefer not to add a new package to the server just for this (it's an edge case, so I might forget to include that package when setting up a new server), so I went back to the version with tabular. Below is the result (showing two pages so you can see how the functions get called). The result looks okay except that the vertical placement of the box is too low (halfway off the bottom of the page). \dimexpr 10mm+\dp\tempbox was previously working to give it a nice 10mm margin, so I don't know what happened.
\documentclass{ujarticle}
\usepackage{plext}
\usepackage[uplatex]{otf}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\graphicspath {{/var/www/kizunadb/public/graphics/}}

%FUNCTION #1 "preamble"
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\noindent
\raggedright
\sffamily
\gtfamily

%FUNCTION #2 "loop start"
\savebox\tempbox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% use only as much space as needed
\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\selectfont 5 copies\\
Doe, John (1)\\
Jones, Samuel \& Sally (1)\\
Smith, George (3)
\end{tabular}}}% measures size for use later

\begin{picture}(210,297)(3,3)
%Other stuff on page (omitted for brevity)

%FUNCTION #3 "page end"
\put({\dimexpr 200mm-\wd\tempbox},{\dimexpr 10mm+\dp\tempbox}){\usebox\tempbox}

\end{picture}
\clearpage

%FUNCTION #2 "loop start"
\savebox\tempbox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% use only as much space as needed
\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\selectfont 5 copies\\
Doe, John (1)\\
Jones, Samuel \& Sally (1)\\
Smith, George (3)
\end{tabular}}}% measures size for use later

\begin{picture}(210,297)(3,3)
%Other stuff on page (omitted for brevity)

%FUNCTION #3 "page end"
\put({\dimexpr 200mm-\wd\tempbox},{\dimexpr 10mm+\dp\tempbox}){\usebox\tempbox}

\end{picture}
\clearpage
\end{document}


Please provide some code for people to play with. This should be a complete but minimal document we can compile to reproduce the situation. As far as I know, it should be \put(x,y){<content>} so I'd expect \put{x,y} to give an error. A tikz node or a tcolorbox can adapt to both the width and height of content, but fbox cannot do so on its own. \linewidth varies depending on context. Since you've given none, it is hard to say what it is equal to. \put doesn't change the alignment of the thing put. If you put something aligned bottom right, it will be bottom right.

@cfr Oops, I meant \put(X,Y). I edited the question to fix that and include example code. Sorry for all the packages - my environment needs to accommodate a lot of stuff not relevant to this, like vertically written Japanese text, images, etc. All the rest is working - I'm just trying to add this little info box.

Sorry - probably my ignorance - but what are you compiling this with? I tried platex, but it complains that encoding JY2 is unknown ....

@cfr It's compiled by uplatex (I don't remember whether that comes with texlive or I added it to the server later - it has been a long time since I set up the server), and then the resulting .dvi file is processed by another command called dvipdfmx to make a PDF file. I don't compile it at the command line; the two commands are executed by PHP code after it generates the .tex file at request of online users, to serve them the resulting PDF. I wrote most of the TeX-related code over a decade ago, with a lot of guidance from others who actually understand LaTeX - I really struggle with it.

The left baseline is being placed at (105,50).  The default baseline for \parbox is at the vertical center (more or less).  With a nonzero offfset, the picture is too big for the page, and \linewidth pushies the parbox way off the page.

@JohnKormylo But the vertical alignment is trickier - at least for me.

I deleted my answer because it won't work with uplatex/dvipdfmx. Something is adding colour specials it doesn't like.

You probably know there are now easier ways to typeset Japanese ....

@cfr If just typesetting, sure - I use Japanese all the time in InDesign. Are there easier ways to start with PHP and end up with a PDF? This particular case is laying out addresses on envelopes and postcards in proper Japanese format (sometimes "tategaki" writing orientation), and another even more challenging one creates songsheets on demand with color-coded guitar chords written above the corresponding syllables, avoiding drift or overlap by forcing word separation if the chords are too long (using lots of tiny tabular bits). If there are easier ways, I'm all ears.

@OsakaWebbie I was thinking within TeX. LuaTeX, for instance would probably make things easier and produce a PDF in one step. There's specialist packages for Japanese, in particular. E.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatexja. (Not saying that's the best option. Just one I happen to be aware of.) It's a later development than upTeX which uses Lua rather than requiring a custom engine. You may or may not like it, but it is probably worth a look. I don't know anything about PHP but I'd assume if you can do it with upTeX, you should be able to do it with LuaTeX.

@cfr Okay, I'll take a look at LuaTeX when I have spare time (not right now, as I need to get this and several other things done on a tight deadline). I need to also rebuild my server sometime relatively soon, so that might be a good time to change TeX flavors if appropriate.

For what it's worth, the disappearing off the bottom of the page is why I ended up using coffins. Does the problem disappear if you don't change font size?

@cfr I don't know what coffins are, but even with no font changes, it still goes slightly more than half off the page. (There are, of course, font sizes specified for other things on the page, but they are all in their own \put{} sections.) Log complains on the \put...usebox line: "!A  was supposed to be here." Changing the Y value to a simple constant puts the middle of the box at that point and that error disappears, but any expression involving /dp/tempbox throws that error and is ignored.

They're one of the newer LaTeX features. A bit like boxes, but you can join them together and align them using 'poles', which typically makes it easier to construct and place things where you want them. Underrated, I think. So, basically, my idea was to put each line in a temporary coffin, attach that to an output coffin and then do the same with the next line etc. Once all the lines were done, I placed the output coffin at the lower right of the page, using the intersection between the 'pole' at the bottom of the coffin and the 'pole' at the right & it's just wide enough. dvipdfmx hated it.

Haha! I just discovered that the \newsavebox{\tempbox} line (which was added by John in response to "Undefined control sequence") was causing the vertical placement problem - go figure! Simply removing that line made it well. So I only need two custom function calls: one before \begin{picture} (to define tempbox) and the second before \end{picture} (to put the box). There are all kinds of warnings in the log, but the code does draw the stuff where I need it to be.

This makes the box as small as needed and measures the resulting size.  The \put using absolute units (ignoring \unitlength) places the left baseline above the lower right corner.  This does not depend on where the baseline actually is.
%\documentclass{ujarticle}% I don't want to read all the manuals or mess with xelatex
%\usepackage{plext}
%\usepackage[uplatex]{otf}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\graphicspath {{/var/www/kizunadb/public/graphics/}}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\noindent
\raggedright% ???
\sffamily
%\gtfamily

\begin{picture}(210,297)(0,0)
\savebox\tempbox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont% default
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% use only as much space as needed
  \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
  5 copies\\
  Doe, John (1)\\
  Jones, Samuel \& Sally (1)\\
  Smith, George (3)
  \end{tabular}}}% measure size
\put({\dimexpr 210mm-\wd\tempbox},\dp\tempbox){\usebox\tempbox}
\end{picture}

\clearpage% >>>
\end{document}


Unlike my answer, this works fine with uplatex + dvipdfmx.

This kinda works for me, but is it necessary to be outside of picture mode when doing the savebox stuff? The code that makes the box is a custom function that is called after the rest of the page elements are placed, and although I can start the custom function with \end{picture}, that forces the box to be on another page. Also, there are two formatting oddities when I use it: (1) the \fboxsep doesn't seem to work; (2) John Doe is the right size, but Jones and Smith are considerably smaller for some mysterious reason. Any clues?

I solved the fboxsep issue by moving the setlength before the savebox stuff. I also experimented with staying in picture mode - that did allow everything to be on the same page, but instead of Jones and Smith being smaller than Doe (10pt), they were significantly larger (30pt) and all the line spacing was bigger. And either way, the log file has multiple "Undefined control sequence" complaints (the first being " \tempbox") and a couple "Bad register code" ones (about \org@put..., which isn't in my code).

It seems that \selcetfont only affects one line in a tabular, so I switched to varwidth.  Sorry about the \fboxsep.   I have no idea what effect picture has on anything else (it's been years since I last used it), so was simply avoiding possible conflicts.

@JohnKormylo I can do \selectfont for each line. To add packages or declare the savebox, I'd have to add to the core code a call to an additional custom function in the preamble. And to define the box for each page outside the picture environment would require a third such call inside the page-building loop but before the \begin{picture}. Yes, I can add those calls, but... In my MWE, I put a blank line before and after the place where my current call is, and of course you're not seeing the core content that goes on each page, nor multiple pages - it's an MWE.

Okay, back to tabular and no \tempbox.

Hmm, with your new sans-tempbox code, the box is gone. Log says: "! A  was supposed to be here.

\unitlength
l.60 ...mexpr 210\unitlength-\wd0},\dp0){\usebox0}
I was expecting to see \hbox or \vbox or \copy or \box or
something like that. So you might find something missing in
your output." Note that I previously updated my question with my best code iteration so far - perhaps you can help with the last little issue.

I decided to go ahead and do the three-function-call thing, but I apparently did something wrong with the vertical placement. See Update #2 in my question.

Needless to say, I don't get this error.  The new code uses box register 0. Box registers 0-9 are supposed to be free for use, but you occasionally get conflicts with other code, even though I am careful to only use them locally (inside a group).

I just found out that your previous version (my modified version of which is in "Update #2" in my question) works if I don't declare \newsavebox{\tempbox}! Of course I get the "Undefined control sequence" complaint (and there are multiple other complaints), but the PDF looks like I want it to look. For future readers, you might want to restore that code to your answer (I don't know why the sbox0 thing didn't work for me, but it didn't), and I'll mark it as the answer.
